# WCF deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wcf, soap

Please help me out to get this fixed... Its been ages I'm trying to solve this.

I'm writing a wcf service which consumes a third party service as service reference.  And this wcf service will be used in a client to send soap xml messages.

While using xml serializer the client code to deserialize an xml file works but some of the properties are null; which worked while using a asmx web service.  Please let me know if I'm missing something.

The wcf service is below,

```
[ServiceBehavior(Namespace = "http://somethirdparty.com/2011")]
    [SoapDocumentService(ParameterStyle=SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]    
public class Service : IService
{        
    [SoapDocumentMethod(ParameterStyle=SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
    public OTA_HotelResNotifRS ReservationNotification(OTA_HotelResNotifRQ OTA_HotelResNotifRQ)
    {
...........
}

[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://somethirdparty.com/2011")]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
public interface IService
{           
    [OperationContract (Action="http://somethirdparty.com/2011/RS/HotelResNotif")]
    [return: MessageParameter(Name = "OTA_HotelResNotifRS")]
    OTA_HotelResNotifRS ReservationNotification(OTA_HotelResNotifRQ OTA_HotelResNotifRQ);        

}
```

The client code is below

```
LotusResNotifService.OTA_HotelResNotifRQ OTA_HotelResNotifRQ = new LotusResNotifService.OTA_HotelResNotifRQ();

        XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
        xRoot.ElementName = "OTA_HotelResNotifRQ";
        xRoot.IsNullable = true;
        xRoot.Namespace = "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05";

        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(OTA_HotelResNotifRQ.GetType(), xRoot);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\HotelResNotifRQ_SOAP_RQ.xml");
        object deserialized = deserializer.Deserialize(reader.BaseStream);
        OTA_HotelResNotifRQ = (LotusResNotifService.OTA_HotelResNotifRQ)deserialized;
```

The OTA_HotelResNotifRQ has some of the properties returned as null though the xml elements and values are present...

The request model, OTA_HotelResNotifRQ

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34230")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05")]
public partial class OTA_HotelResNotifRQ : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private SourceType[] pOSField;

    private UniqueID_Type messageIDField;

    private HotelReservationsType hotelReservationsField;

    private string echoTokenField;

    private System.DateTime timeStampField;

    private bool timeStampFieldSpecified;

    private OTA_HotelAvailNotifRQTarget targetField;

    private bool targetFieldSpecified;

    private string targetNameField;

    private decimal versionField;

    private string transactionIdentifierField;

    private string sequenceNmbrField;

    private OTA_HotelAvailNotifRQTransactionStatusCode transactionStatusCodeField;

    private bool transactionStatusCodeFieldSpecified;

    private bool retransmissionIndicatorField;

    private bool retransmissionIndicatorFieldSpecified;

    private string correlationIDField;

    private TransactionActionType resStatusField;

    private bool resStatusFieldSpecified;

    private string holdDurationField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Source", IsNullable=false)]
    public SourceType[] POS {
        get {
            return this.pOSField;
        }
        set {
            this.pOSField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("POS");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=1)]
    public UniqueID_Type MessageID {
        get {
            return this.messageIDField;
        }
        set {
            this.messageIDField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("MessageID");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=2)]
    public HotelReservationsType HotelReservations {
        get {
            return this.hotelReservationsField;
        }
        set {
            this.hotelReservationsField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("HotelReservations");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string EchoToken {
        get {
            return this.echoTokenField;
        }
        set {
            this.echoTokenField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("EchoToken");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public System.DateTime TimeStamp {
        get {
            return this.timeStampField;
        }
        set {
            this.timeStampField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("TimeStamp");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool TimeStampSpecified {
        get {
            return this.timeStampFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.timeStampFieldSpecified = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("TimeStampSpecified");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public OTA_HotelAvailNotifRQTarget Target {
        get {
            return this.targetField;
        }
        set {
            this.targetField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Target");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool TargetSpecified {
        get {
            return this.targetFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.targetFieldSpecified = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("TargetSpecified");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string TargetName {
        get {
            return this.targetNameField;
        }
        set {
            this.targetNameField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("TargetName");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public decimal Version {
        get {
            return this.versionField;
        }
        set {
            this.versionField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Version");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string TransactionIdentifier {
        get {
            return this.transactionIdentifierField;
        }
        set {
            this.transactionIdentifierField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("TransactionIdentifier");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType="nonNegativeInteger")]
    public string SequenceNmbr {
        get {
            return this.sequenceNmbrField;
        }
        set {
            this.sequenceNmbrField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("SequenceNmbr");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public OTA_HotelAvailNotifRQTransactionStatusCode TransactionStatusCode {
        get {
            return this.transactionStatusCodeField;
        }
        set {
            this.transactionStatusCodeField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("TransactionStatusCode");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool TransactionStatusCodeSpecified {
        get {
            return this.transactionStatusCodeFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.transactionStatusCodeFieldSpecified = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("TransactionStatusCodeSpecified");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public bool RetransmissionIndicator {
        get {
            return this.retransmissionIndicatorField;
        }
        set {
            this.retransmissionIndicatorField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("RetransmissionIndicator");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool RetransmissionIndicatorSpecified {
        get {
            return this.retransmissionIndicatorFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.retransmissionIndicatorFieldSpecified = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("RetransmissionIndicatorSpecified");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string CorrelationID {
        get {
            return this.correlationIDField;
        }
        set {
            this.correlationIDField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("CorrelationID");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public TransactionActionType ResStatus {
        get {
            return this.resStatusField;
        }
        set {
            this.resStatusField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("ResStatus");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool ResStatusSpecified {
        get {
            return this.resStatusFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.resStatusFieldSpecified = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("ResStatusSpecified");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType="duration")]
    public string HoldDuration {
        get {
            return this.holdDurationField;
        }
        set {
            this.holdDurationField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("HoldDuration");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And the xml,

```
<OTA_HotelResNotifRQ Version="2.001" Target="Production" PrimaryLangID="en-us" ResStatus="Commit" TimeStamp="2010-11-16T07:11:41">
<POS>
<RequestorID Type="22" ID="RR" />
<BookingChannel Type="2" Primary="1">
<CompanyName Code="02200">ABC</CompanyName>
</BookingChannel>
</POS>
<HotelReservations>
<HotelReservation CreateDateTime="2010-11-16" CreatorID="FLAUA" LastModifierID="" LastModifyDateTime="">
<UniqueID Type="14" ID="9709316" />
<RoomStays>
<RoomStay>
    <RatePlan RatePlanCode="">
        <MealsIncluded MealPlanIndicator="0" MealPlanCodes="" MealPlanDescription="" />
    </RatePlan>
    <RoomRates>
        <RoomRate RoomTypeCode="29" RatePlanCode="10" NumberOfUnits="1">
            <Rates>
                <Rate RateTimeUnit="Day" UnitMultiplier="1" EffectiveDate="2011-02-21" ExpireDate="2011-02-22">
                    <Base AmountAfterTax="100.0" CurrencyCode="EUR" />
                </Rate>
                <Rate RateTimeUnit="Day" UnitMultiplier="1" EffectiveDate="2011-02-22" ExpireDate="2011-02-23">
                    <Base AmountAfterTax="73.0" CurrencyCode="EUR" />
                </Rate>
            </Rates>
        </RoomRate>
    </RoomRates>
    <GuestCounts>
        <GuestCount AgeQualifyingCode="10" Count="1" />
        <GuestCount AgeQualifyingCode="8" Count="0" />
    </GuestCounts>
    <TimeSpan Start="2011-02-21" End="2011-02-23" />
    <Guarantee GuaranteeCode="Credit Card" GuaranteeType="CC/DC/Voucher">
        <GuaranteesAccepted>
            <GuaranteeAccepted>
                <PaymentCard CardType="1" CardCode="VI" CardNumber="4444333322221111" ExpireDate="0111" SeriesCode="123">(will not be sent in future)
                    <CardHolderName>Test</CardHolderName>
                </PaymentCard>
            </GuaranteeAccepted>
        </GuaranteesAccepted>
    </Guarantee>
    <Total CurrencyCode="EUR" AmountAfterTax="173.0">
        <Taxes Amount="0.0" CurrenyCode="" />
    </Total>
    <BasicPropertyInfo HotelCode="21449" />
    <Comments>
        <Comment GuestViewable="1">
            <Text />
        </Comment>
        <Comment GuestViewable="0">
            <Text />
        </Comment>
    </Comments>
    <SpecialRequests>
        <SpecialRequest RequestCode="">
            <Text />
        </SpecialRequest>
        <SpecialRequest RequestCode="">
            <Text />
        </SpecialRequest>
    </SpecialRequests>
</RoomStay>
</RoomStays>
<ResGuests>
<ResGuest ResGuestRPH="1">
    <Profiles>
        <ProfileInfo>
            <Profile ProfileType="1">
                <Customer>
                    <PersonName>
                        <NamePrefix />
                        <GivenName>tr</GivenName>
                        <Surname>Test</Surname>
                    </PersonName>
                    <Telephone PhoneLocationType="7" PhoneTechType="1" PhoneNumber="+91-9831012345" FormattedInd="1" />
                    <Email EmailType="2"></Email>
                    <Address Type="1">
                        <AddressLine />
                        <CityName />
                        <StateProv StateCode="" />
                        <PostalCode />
                        <CountryName Code="" />
                    </Address>
                </Customer>
            </Profile>
        </ProfileInfo>
    </Profiles>
    <ArrivalTransport>
        <TransportInfo Time="" Type="" ID="" />
    </ArrivalTransport>
    <DepartureTransport>
        <TransportInfo Time="" Type="" ID="" />
    </DepartureTransport>
</ResGuest>
</ResGuests>
<ResGlobalInfo>
<HotelReservationIDs>
    <HotelReservationID ResID_Type="14" ResID_Value="" />
</HotelReservationIDs>
</ResGlobalInfo>
</HotelReservation>
</HotelReservations>
</OTA_HotelResNotifRQ>
```

The inner nodes of HotelReservations, POS, ResGlobalInfo etc turned null on deserialization...

Comment: Can you please specify xml content and OTA_HotelResNotifRQ model? It will help another person to find the exact issue.

Comment: Sure, let me edit the post with xml and OTA model...

Comment: Anyone there to throw some light on this?

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.  Your question doesn't include your classes for HotelReservations, POS, or ResGlobalInfo and so doesn't even compile.  We have no way to determine the problem based on this.